# How to set custom max connection pool size in @feignclient configuration in spring

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, feign

How to set custom max connection pool size in `@feignclient` configuration in spring ,

```
@FeignClient(name = "content-cms", configuration = ContentCmsServiceFeignConfig.class)
public interface FeignService {

@RequestMapping(value = "/test/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
String getSample(@RequestParam("token") String token, @RequestParam("cid") String cid,
        @RequestParam("ratio") String ratio, @RequestParam("s") String source);

}
```

Comment: what thread pool are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about connection pool,Where by default i can see only 200 connection pool size.Can i increase that.is there any way

Comment: @robp can you please elaborate on this,I can see you used the same in query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153138/spring-cloud-feign-and-http-connection-pooling

Answer (score 15):

You can configure the number of connections within the specific `Client` implementation used.  Feign has out of the box support `Apache Http`, `OkHttp` and `Ribbon`.  When using `Spring Cloud Open Feign`, the default client is based on what you have in your classpath.

Here is an example using `Apache Http`, you can configure your own `CloseableHttpClient` bean with the settings you want.

```java
@Configuration
public class HttpClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() {
       return HttpClients.custom()
                  .maxConnectionsPerRoute(200)
                  .maxConnections(200)
                  .build()
    }
}
```

If you are using Spring Boot, you can configure any of the `feign.httpclient.*` properties as well.

```
feign:
   httpclient:
       maxConnections: 200
       maxConnectionsPerRoute: 200
```

You can find more information in the [Spring Cloud OpenFeign Documentation: Overriding Feign Defaults](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults)

Comment: In order to complete this answer with a detail that kept me struggling for a whole day: you need to add a bridge between Feign and Apache HttpClient. e.g.:     `<dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
   <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Comment: link corrupted. Maybe is this? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html