# Spring Cloud - Feign - Number of threads

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, threadpool, spring-cloud-feign

I am new with Feign so I want to study and use Feign.
Does default number of threads of Feign is 200 which is the same default number of threads in Tomcat?
As Feign is a web service client and it has asynchronous call to external systems, how many maximum number of threads Feign will created? (assume that my micro service running on Kubernetes, it can scale out to 6 instances, each instance has 2GB MB memory and 2CPUs, total number of request per day is 2M requests).

I refer to [thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153138/spring-cloud-feign-and-http-connection-pooling)   [max-connection-pool-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779354/how-to-set-custom-max-connection-pool-size-in-feignclient-configuration-in-spri)

would you help to share about maximum number of threads of feign and what is pros and cons when I use feign instead of using RestTemplate?

Comment: The major difference between RestTemplate and Feign is Feign is declarative and RestTemplate is imperative. The each use an underlying HTTP client.